# Can't find a "friction screw" for a friction shifting system

Tags: shifter, parts, vintage, mechanical, adjustment-screw

I recently broke one of the two speed levers ajuster (friction screw) that adjust the pressure between the levers and the cable. It's made in plastic as shown in the picture below. I would like to know if someone know the real name of this part and if I can find it somewhere. I have looked on internet but cannot find anything.

Otherwise, maybe someone could have an idea of a part that could replace this one. It's sitting around (and in the back) of a 8 size hexagonal head.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

enter image description here
[image]
[image]
[image: Good condition]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Do you have the broken part still with you? If so, sharing a close-up image of it might help with its identification, as figuring out the brand of the shifter lever.

Comment: You could try unscrewing the bolt from the other side. Checking the size /thread on that bolt and buying a replacement for the missing side (both sides will use the same bolt). I'm guessing its an M6 bolt

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you! I will try to find something like a "wing bolt" with the same size so that it could replace this one.